# What is Perl's equivalent to Ruby's Pry

Tags: ruby, perl, pry

I was wondering what Perl's equivalent to Ruby's pry is?

Lets say I have a block of ruby code

```
CSV.foreach('teamss.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  binding.pry
  team_array << row.to_hash
end
```

I can insert that binding.pry to then go to the commandlind and go to pry. From here I can type out team_array and get an output of whats currently in the hash at that iteration through the loop. I then can press next and see the next iteration through the loop. This way I can follow what's going on in the code line by line right in the terminal.

If I wanted to do something like this in Perl is there something available? That lets me see what exactly is happening in a loop at each iteration or something that at least lets me see what the finished loop is actually spitting out. That way I can see where in a large code base something might be breaking down.

If I wanted to put such a thing in this block of perl code. I was asking for an example of what it would look like. Within the block of code below or one of your own choosing. Or a simple yeah you can use this, or no there is no such thing.

```
foreach my $secert (@secert) {

    my @example = $self->getMissingSecerts({secert=>$secert});
    next if !@example;

    $self->send_page({page=>"checksecerts/secert", param=>{secert=>$secert,      example=>\@example}});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do in English instead of in Ruby?

Comment: Basically looking for a way to track whats in a given data structure, line by line.

Comment: Inspired by this question, I've just released [Pry](https://metacpan.org/release/Pry) on CPAN. It's not by any means identical to the Ruby tool of the same name, but should be useful for similar purposes.

Comment: Thank You a bunch. I just noticed this and could not be more happier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this CPAN module available.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Pry

Comment: Ha, just spotted tobyink already mentioned he created it for this question. Good old Perl Weekly.

Answer (score 3):

Perl doesn't have a direct equivalent to Pry. For your particular example I'd use the debugger. You don't need to add anything to your source code. Just invoke perl with the `-d` option:

```
perl -d script.pl
```

From there, it's a matter of using debugger commands. Some of the more commonly used ones are:

- `b` set a breakpoint
- `c` continue
- `s` single step (step into)
- `n` next (step over)
- `r` step return
- `x` examine variable
- `q` quit

See [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) for full details.

e.g. assuming that `my @example = ...` is on line 100 of your script and that's the variable you want to check each time through the loop:

```
C:\>perl -d script.pl
...
DB<1> b 101
...
DB<2> c
...
DB<3> x \@example
```

Comment: To make this a more direct equivalent, you can put `$DB::single = 1;` in your code where you want it to drop into the debugger shell.  Then just run it under the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

1) You could just use a print() statement:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data = (
    {a => 1, b => 2},
    {c => 3, d => 4},
    {a => 5, b => 6},
);

my %team_hash;

for my $href (@data) {
    %team_hash = %$href;

    print "$_ $team_hash{$_}\n" for (keys %team_hash);
    say '-' x 10;
}

--output:--
a 1
b 2
----------
c 3
d 4
----------
a 5
b 6
----------
```

2) Or, you could use Data::Dumper:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data = (
    {a => 1, b => 2},
    {c => 3, d => 4},
    {a => 5, b => 6},
);

my %team_hash;

for my $href (@data) {
    say Dumper(\$href);
    %team_hash = %$href;
}

--output:--
$VAR1 = \{
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => 2
          };

$VAR1 = \{
            'c' => 3,
            'd' => 4
          };

$VAR1 = \{
            'a' => 5,
            'b' => 6
          };
```

3) Or, you could use perl's debugger (see [perl debugger tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebtut.html)):

```
~/perl_programs$ perl -d my_prog.pl 

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(1.pl:6): my @data = (
main::(1.pl:7):     {a => 1, b => 2},
main::(1.pl:8):     {c => 3, d => 4},
main::(1.pl:9):     {a => 5, b => 6},
main::(1.pl:10):    );
  DB<1> v   #Show the `view` where the debugger stopped in the code
3:  use 5.016;
4:  use Data::Dumper;
5   
6==>    my @data = (
7       {a => 1, b => 2},
8       {c => 3, d => 4},
9       {a => 5, b => 6},
10  );
11  
12: my %team_hash;
  DB<1> v   #Show more of the view
10  );
11  
12: my %team_hash;
13  
14: for my $href (@data) {
15:     %team_hash = %$href;
16  }
17  
18  
  DB<1> s    #Step to the next line
main::(1.pl:12):    my %team_hash;
  DB<1> s
main::(1.pl:14):    for my $href (@data) {
  DB<1> s
main::(1.pl:15):        %team_hash = %$href;
  DB<1> p %team_hash   #No output because the debugger halted at the beginning of the line

  DB<2> s
main::(1.pl:15):        %team_hash = %$href;
  DB<2> p %team_hash   #Print the variable
a1b2
  DB<3>
```